# UITextView in a UITableViewCell: first responder problem

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, first-responder

I have a UITextView in a UITableViewCell which grows together with it.
Using

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```

in `textViewDidChange` and setting the height of the cell properly, I'm getting close to the solution.
But I've a problem tied to the first responder.
I set the textview in my custom cell to become the first responder ('cause I want to start with the open keyboard) on the view loading, but the textview is nil in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, only when I write a char I can see it's not nil.

I connected the textview in the IB custom cell with an IBOutlet in my viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved putting

```
[myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```